# Validity Comparision in java

Tags: java, date, time, compare

Hey everyone in my web application i am generating a verification code that is to be entered by user for account activation. I want that the generated verification code should be valid for specific time period say 12 hrs or 24 hrs. I am storing details of date and time when code  is generated but how  can i check for validity means suppose user entered code how can i check  that he has entered code in validation period or not? How to compare date and time together? Thanks

Comment: It's not clear what the problem actually is. I would just use standard date/time functions to convert the generated time and the entered time into a format that has a subtraction operator that returns seconds. What exactly is going wrong?

Comment: My problem is when user register to out site system generates a code that is valid for say 12 or 24 hrs. I want to make sure that if user has entered the code in validation period.

Comment: Okay, so do that. When the user enters the code, look up the time the code was generated in the database. Subtract that from the current time and compare to the the appropriate number of seconds. Or, to be lazy, store the expiration time in the database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't think of it as a date and time as such. I'd think of it as an *instant in time*. When you generate the verification code, work out the instant in time "24 hours from now", and store that. Then just check "the current instant" when you validate the verification code.

You could use `System.currentTimeMillis()` to get the instant as a `long` value in milliseconds. (It's since the Unix epoch, but that's actually irrelevant here.) In fact, I'd suggest you create a kind of `Clock` interface which can be used to determine the current instant, with an implementation using `System.currentTimeMillis()` - or the [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) equivalent. That way you can unit test your code more easily.

So take the current number of milliseconds, add your appropriate duration to it (again, in milliseconds), and that's your expiry instant.

Comment: but i am just a student i don't know how to add time or milliseconds. Will you please help me to get out of this? And how to get Milliseconds of 24 hrs

Comment: @kanchan: I'm not going to tell you how to work out how many milliseconds are in 24 hours - any student should be able to do that themselves. (Small hint: how many milliseconds are in a second? How many seconds are in a minute... work up from there.) Once you've got that, it's just a case of adding two `long` values together.

Comment: I need one more help. I did what u said. i took current Milliseconds and added Milliseconds for 5 mins (just to check) .I am having addition of two long numbers. And now when user enters code What should i compare. Should i take milliseconds of current time again or what ?

Comment: @kanchan: Yes, exactly. (It's worth making sure you understand *why* you're doing this... are you confused about anything else?)

Answer (score 2):

Use a database such as my sql to store verification code. have a field called createdTime. When user tries to verify, subtract createdTime from now() to get less than 24.

RESPONSE: date subtraction

```
 select something from someTable where createdTime >= date_sub(now(), interval 24 hour)
```

Comment: yup i am doing same. i have mysql databse. But how to do substraction of time

Comment: anytime! today you need help, tomorrow I will need help. :)

Answer (score 1):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html

after() and before() methods do ecactly what you want.

Comment: There's really no need for a `Date` here. Just a "number of milliseconds" is very easy to store and compare...

Comment: True that. Damn, I hate you :). I'll leave it here as an alternative, but the upvote goes to you, ofc. Btw in my point of view, there's never a need for java.util.Date...

Answer (score 1):

The Java Date class has before() and after() functions for comparing dates.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `before` or `after` of [Calender](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) object
For example:

```
// initialize ur date here
Date issueded = null;

Calendar issuedDate = Calendar.getInstance();
issuedDate.setTime(issueded);

Calendar expiredDate = Calendar.getInstance();
// minus 12 H
expiredDate.add(Calendar.HOUR, -12);
if(expiredDate.before(issuedDate)) {
    // do ur thing
} else {
    // expired
}
```